# FireMonkey Android acceleration sensor high cpu usage

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, sensors, delphi-10.1-berlin

When I try to use the acceleration sensor in Android it causes high CPU usage - even when I try to stop the sensor by code and deactivate it.

I just need to read the acceleration sensor once in my app but it looks like the FireMonkey doesn't respond and can't stop the sensor.

Here is the code:

```
var
  Sensor: TCustomSensor;
begin
   { attempt to get and activate the sensor manager }
  FSensorManager := TSensorManager.Current;
  FSensorManager.Activate;

  { attempt to get an orientation sensor }
  FSensors := TSensorManager.Current.GetSensorsByCategory(TSensorCategory.Motion);

  FSensor := nil;
  for Sensor in FSensors do
    if TCustomMotionSensor(Sensor).SensorType = TMotionSensorType.Accelerometer3D then
    begin
      FSensor := TCustomMotionSensor(Sensor);
      Break;
    end;

  if not Assigned(FSensor) then
  begin
    Exit; { no orientation sensor is available }
  end;

  { start the sensor if it is not started }
  if not FSensor.Started then
  begin
    FSensor.Start;
    Timer1.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;
```

I try to stop sensor by:

```
FSensor.Stop;
FSensorManager.Deactivate;
FSensor.Free;
FSensorManager.Free;
```

but looks like this doesn't work at all!

Here are screenshots that show the increase in CPU usage:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAbVF.jpg)

[After pushing button and activated sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOZJA.jpg)

Comment: You've neglected to mention the product version use. Please rectify this by editing your question.

Comment: Also, can you clarify... you're saying that your attempt to deactivate the sensor does not deactivate the sensor, so far as the app's CPU usage indicates? Is this an assumption? Can you prove the point by seeing events still fired after you deactivate the sensor? 
Please add more detail to the question to quell the need for "reading between the lines" on the part of anyone looking at your question.

Comment: I use " Rad studio 10.1 update 1" . when the  "FSensor.Start" executed suddenly the cell phone CPU usage increases to 20%! and doesn't decrease until i close the app even when in the code i deactivate and free the" Fsensor" and "FSensorManager".

Comment: And for completeness, which tool are you using to assess CPU usage?

Comment: In what way are you able to prove that it's your sensor which is causing this CPU usage? Can you show us, for example, a screenshot of this tool?

Comment: I added the screenshots. i use the android active app tools. Its 100% clear that accessing sensor in my app cause this problem because before pushing the button the CPU usage is low but after that goes crazy  ! and there is no way to stop it. I test the app on 3 cellphone with different   android version but the problem is the same. Even i use the "Tmotionsensor" component but same problem. once the "motionsensor.active:=true" the CPU usage jumps up and there is no way to no way to stop it. even if you deactivate the "motionsensor" by "motionsensor.active:=false;"

Comment: I can reproduce the issue readily using another CPU monitor. Disabling the sensor and deactivating the sensor manager does not undo the massive CPU [sp|h]ike. I did look into this back in XE6 days for someone, so I'll see if I can revisit whatever I came up with.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is down to what appears to be an oversight in the FireMonkey Android sensor implementation. What happens is this:

When you [activate the sensor manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Sensors.TSensorManager.Activate) on Android you invoke `TAndroidSensorManager.Activate`. This tries to instantiate a [`TCustomSensor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Sensors.TCustomSensor) descendant for all the known Android sensor types, quickly removing any that are found to not be supported on the current device. This leaves the manager managing a bunch of custom sensor objects, each of which has created a `TNativeSensor` object with a [sensor type enumeration value](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___sensor.html#enum-members), as defined in the Androidapi.Sensor unit.

No big deal so far. Each `TNativeSensor` object constructor has called a couple of NDK routines to set things up: [`ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___sensor.html#gaf4880d87e01f5e2d4a9b8403e4047445) and [`ASensorManager_createEventQueue`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___sensor.html#gac46f8b28bcc7a846dea9d841cab0a67b). Thus far there is no noticeable impact on the CPU.

[Starting the sensor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Sensors.TCustomSensor.Start) causes the underlying `TNativeSensor` to call the NDK [`ASensorEventQueue_enableSensor`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___sensor.html#ga48a8379cf9de9b09a71a00f8a3699499) routine, and this is where the CPU is pummeled.

[Stopping the custom sensor object](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Sensors.TCustomSensor.Stop) calls [`ASensorEventQueue_disableSensor`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___sensor.html#ga03852b813887ec236a34c4aef0df4b68), which you might think would cease the CPU usage. However this doesn't actually seem to be the case.

To properly remove the CPU usage from a sensor it seems (just by practical experimentation) that you need to destroy the native sensor event queue, i.e. undo the earlier call to [`ASensorManager_createEventQueue`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___sensor.html#gac46f8b28bcc7a846dea9d841cab0a67b). However the FireMonkey Android code does not do this. There is no call to [`ASensorManager_destroyEventQueue`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___sensor.html#gaf35624037785cdea1e7fe9e0a73fc5e1) present in the code.

What this means is that even if you set all your references to sensors and sensor managers to `nil` and all those sensor objects, including the internal ones, get destroyed then you still get a CPU hit: ಠ╭╮ಠ

The only way I can get behaviour that seems valid in Delphi 10.1 Berlin (without the Update, currently) is to modify System.Android.Sensors.pas. If you want to do likewise to test this theory out, here are the steps:

- In your project make a new folder called RTL
- Into this RTL folder copy $(BDS)\source\rtl\common\System.Android.Sensors.pas where $(BDS) is your Delphi installation folder
- Add this copied file to your project using the project manager.

Now make these changes to the copied System.Android.Sensors.pas. In `TNativeSensor`'s public section add in a destructor declaration:

```
destructor Destroy; override;
```

Implement the destructor:

```
destructor TNativeSensor.Destroy;
begin
  ASensorManager_destroyEventQueue(FSensorManager, FNativeEventQueue);
  inherited;
end;
```

Compile and run and the CPU hit should drop off entirely when all your references to the sensor objects are set to `nil`.

Comment: I'll log a bug on this.

Comment: This  totally  solves the problem and reduce CPU usage. Thanks for your help.